# SQL server join query to get all subjects

Tags: join, sql-server-2005

I have the three tables:

`TBL_SUBJECT`, `TBL_SEMESTER` and `TBL_SUBJECT_SEMESTER_MAPPING`

I am having `subjectId` with me say '1', I want to get All the subjects of the semester to which my subject belongs. i.e subject having Id '1'.

How is the query with joins in SQL server.

Comment: i have done it like this

**select * from tbl_subject S
inner join tbl_subject_semester_mapping SSP on SSP.subId = S.subId 
inner join tbl_semester SEM on SEM.semId = SSP.semId  
where SEM.semId = (select semId from tbl_subject_semester_mapping  TSSM where TSSM.subId =  1 )**

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not as clear as it could be. Please post schemas to get a better answer.

Answers will be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SEMESTER_NAME 
FROM 
    TBL_SEMESTER 
INNER JOIN 
    TBL_SUBJECT_SEMESTER_MAPPING ON TBL_SUBJECT_SEMESTER_MAPPING.SUBJECTID = TBL_SEMESTER.SUBJECTID
INNER JOIN 
    TBL_SUBJECT TBL ON TBL_SUBJECT.SUBJECTID = TBL_SUBJECT_SEMESTER_MAPPING.SUBJECTID
WHERE 
    SUBJECTNAME LIKE YOURSUBJECT
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this

**SELECT * from tbl_subject S 

INNER JOIN tbl_subject_semester_mapping SSP ON SSP.subId = S.subId

INNER JOIN tbl_semester SEM ON SEM.semId = SSP.semId

WHERE SEM.semId = (select semId from tbl_subject_semester_mapping TSSM where TSSM.subId = 1 )**